# Scala - no data foreach after filter

Tags: scala

```
mylist.filter( ~~~ ).foreach( myItem => ~~ )
```

If there is no matched data through 'filter', foreach method is not executed?

Comment: It's executed, but it won't apply lambda to any element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* executed, it just receives an empty list (the result of `filter`) as the input and so does nothing.